# Cannot catch any events of an ActiveX Image Combo Control in VBA Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, activex

I am using an ActiveX Image Combo Control in my VBA Access application and I have been having a lot of issues with it. There is little to no documentation on it. I am unable to catch any events from the control. I tried using the "on change, on get focus, and on exit events" and none of them work. The events fire when the form is initialized but that is it. Does anyone know what is up with this control? I am debating as to whether I should cut my losses and use a normal combo box without any images.

The full name of the ActiveX Control is "Microsoft ImageComboBox Control, version 6.0"

Here is my debugging code

```
Private Sub ImageCombo8_Change()
  Debug.Print "change"
End Sub

Private Sub ImageCombo8_Enter()
  Debug.Print "entered"
End Sub

Private Sub ImageCombo8_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
  Debug.Print "exit"
End Sub

Private Sub ImageCombo8_GotFocus()
  Debug.Print "focused"
End Sub
```

On initialization, I get these ouputs

```
entered
focused
exit
change
change
```

And nothing happens when I actually do anything to the control.

Setting up the control with items:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim objNewItem As ComboItem
  Set objNewItem = ImageCombo8.ComboItems.Add(1, , "Option 1", "pic1key")
  objNewItem.Indentation = 1
  Set objNewItem = ImageCombo8.ComboItems.Add(2, , "Option 2", "pic2key")
  objNewItem.Indentation = 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Would it be possible to [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I have never been able to successfully use any of the ActiveX controls in Access. I can't find Image Combo Control. How do you implement it? If I can't replicate situation, can't analyze and advise.

Comment: @June7 Thanks for the reply. I provided more details.

Comment: Taking me too much time to figure out how to set up the control. Are you using an ImageList control in conjunction with the ImageCombo? Can you also post the code that sets up these controls?

Comment: Yes I am. I will post my code but this may be helpful in the meantime https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733645(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Already viewed that article. Didn't help with loading the ImageList. Went ahead and tested the ImageCombo GotFocus event. Can confirm doesn't trigger. Don't see a Change event, is an Updated event instead. Just more reason why I have avoided ActiveX controls. If you use, will have to make sure every user has the dll or ocx (whichever it is for this) installed. When I added the ImageCombo to form, Access went through an install process.

Comment: It doesn't show the on change event in the property sheet but when you go to the Form module, you can select the control and the event in their combo boxes. But in any case, it doesn't seem to work. I was suspicious of this particular control from the get go because just to get the value of the currently selected item is complicated. So I might just abandon it altogether. Do you know of any other way of showing an image in a combo list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the GotFocus event only triggered when tabbing into the control, not mouse click. Only the Change event triggers during form load, it does not trigger when item selected, nor does Updated. Enter, Exit, GotFocus, LostFocus all trigger appropriately. Also, the Click event does trigger when an item in the list is clicked.

Here is my working code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim objNewItem As ComboItem, x As Integer
For x = 1 to 2
  Set objNewItem = ImageCombo8.ComboItems.Add(x, , "Option " & x, "pic" & x & "key")
  objNewItem.Indentation = 1
Next
End Sub

Private Sub ImageCombo8_Click()
MsgBox Me.ImageCombo8.SelectedItem.Text
End Sub
```

Even though the ControlSource property shows available on property sheet, it errors if bound to a field. The Value property also fails in code. Use Text property to capture info from the selected item and code to save data to field.

Took forever to figure out how to set up the ImageList and ImageCombo controls. Not a lot of info out there on these critters and most of it involves non-Access programs. Finally discovered that a double click on control in design view opened a dialog box and then found clicking the ellipsis on Custom property does the same.

Comment: I appreciate all your help in figuring out this quirky control. The click event does indeed work as it should. Although it is not as optimal as the on change event, it gets the job done!